# How to add a specific menu item in Panels?

Tags: 7, panels

I am using Drupal 7. I made use of panels to partition the look of a page. I would like to know whether it is possible to add "A specific menu item" in the panels? I have used node templates to generate this page. I have 6 menu items(main menu), i want only one of them to be present in the panels.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, Panels can only interact which *whole* menues.

One option is using [Menu block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) to slice a menu into pieces, exposed as blocks. I don't think menu blocks however can pick *one* item, though I haven't looked at all the advanced options.

If you just want a single menu item, can you just emulate the markup?

Comment: This is what I do-- I just add 'new custom content' and then cut and paste the code from the menu inside.